# How we can list collections from two different tables into single admin grid in Magento 2.3.4?

Tags: magento2

I want to show datas form two different tables in a single Magento admin grid. There is no foreign key relation between these two tables.

Comment: Then you need to do make the relationship between 2 table, then you are able to make it combine.

Comment: @Dhiren Vasoya : I got your point, after that we can use join operation right? But  I cannot make relation ship between these two table.  I have more than two tables. I Need another method like union of these tables.

Comment: If you want to select data the matches between two tables there has to be a criteria that matches them or a link table that has the match data. Then you can do any necessary joins to help you select the data. Figure out the sql you would need to select it in the database first then you can work out the magento functions necessary to make it happen.

Comment: @Mark Rees I don't want join operation, I need union of tables into single grid.

Comment: Have you worked out the sql query you'd use to get the data?

Comment: @Mark Rees. I fetched two table datas as two different collection . I want to merge these two collection into one and list out in single admin grid

Comment: An admin grid usually has a relationship between the different bits of data it displays. If your data from the two queries doesn't have a relationship then why does it need to be in the same grid is a question you should ask yourself. If you are certain you need both sets of unrelated data in your grid then you'll probably need to look at a custom data provider. I can't help with that.

Comment: @MarkRees actually my requirement is  i have two table that contains payment related datas, but there is no foreign key reference between these two tables, I want to show these datas in a single grid. any way thank you for your valuable response.

Comment: @m2dubai you can using "UNION" to combine data multi tables.